# Show HTML Element on Javascript Function Complete

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm using a JavaScript function (GeoLocation) to get a visitors current location. I'm just a Javascript copy and paster so I apologise if the solution to my question is obvious.

Visitors are asked to click a button to get their location, at which point GeoLocation returns that lat and long plus a map - I'm sure you know how it works :)

However, I also want to return a another element (a confirm button - HTML form button) with the completed GeoLocation - not before.

Below is the basic code from my page. Can anyone explain how to hide the form (id = 'form) until a the GeoLocation function has returned a result?

```
<button onclick="getLocation()" id = 'getloc'>Get your location now</button>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<form id = 'confirm'>
<input type = 'hidden' id = 'latitude' value = 'latitude'/>
<input type = 'hidden' id = 'longitude' value = 'longitude'/>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Confirm Your Location'/>
</form>

<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>

<script>
function getLocation(){
  if(!!navigator.geolocation) {
 var map;
 var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 13,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google_canvas'), mapOptions);
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

  var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),latitude=document.getElementById("latitude"),longitude=document.getElementById("longitude");;

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map,
position: geolocate,
    content:
'<h1>Your Current Location</h1>' +
'<h2>Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '</h2>' +
'<h2>Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '</h2>'
  });

  map.setCenter(geolocate);
  latitude.value = position.coords.latitude;
  longitude.value = position.coords.longitude;
});

} else { document.getElementById('map_canvas').innerHTML = 'No Geolocation Support.';
}   
};
</script>
```

Comment: Basically, you want to run some code once the map is loaded?

Comment: Basically, yeah. Not even run - just display.

Comment: Just put the code to hide the element inside the `getCurrentPosition` callback. You are already doing stuff once you get result (like centering the map), so you should know how to do this.

Comment: That does it Felix - or at least pointed out the obvious to me! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I simply added this to the getLocation() function and this solves my problem. As was pointed out, I was doing something similar anyway with the map - just needed to duplicate it for the form element:

```
document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = 
  '<input type = "hidden" id = "latitude" value = "latitude"/>' +
  '<input type = "hidden" id = "longitude" value = "longitude"/>' +
  '<input type = "submit" value = "Confirm Location" />' ;
```

Thanks all for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your form should be hidden by default. Then you could add a listener to google maps:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'event', function)
```

Apparently, the event used by google to tell you that the map is loaded is "idle". So you would have:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
//code to show the form
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mael, my solution is below.

Answer (score 0):

first, hide your form:

```
<form id = 'confirm' style="display: none;">
```

then when geolocation is finished, show it:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    document.getElementById('getloc').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById('confirm').style.display = 'block';
    (...)
});
```

your canvas is named map_canvas and not google_canvas :)

http://jsfiddle.net/PRUpX/